# Remote search for files / folders on Windows

Tags: windows, remote-access

Is there a way to remotely access a Windows system (using a valid username & password, but without changing any default settings of the system or installing new software) and search for files / folders just like how it can be done on Linux systems using SSH?

Comment: have you tried using putty to telnet into a windows system it and access files ????

Comment: Thanks. By default, Telnet is not enabled / installed on Windows 7 (Ref: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/telnet-faq#1TC=windows-7). As stated in query, we are looking for a way to do remote search *without* changing the default settings of the system.

Comment: okay, you are right about putty. but what about winscp ??? i am trying it now between my two windows devices, seems i dont need to configure anything on the remote target pc.

Comment: Thanks. Again as stated in the query, the constraint we have here is that we cannot install  new 3rd party software like WinSCP on remote system.

Comment: you dont need to install winscp on the remote system.. the winscp will be running on your system...

Comment: By default, the firewall is on with no (useful) exceptions.  So, no, you can't do this on a system that has not had at least one configuration change.  (If the username and password are not administrative, additional changes will be needed.)

Comment: @RicoRicochet: Windows does not include an scp server.  You must have installed one yourself at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Malicious File Hunter](http://www.maliciousfilehunter.com/), it can do the search you need on multiple remote computers. Not sure about folders, but it works for files.